# Django, Nginx, Docker with Postgresql on AWS ElasticBeanstalk - could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I am trying to deploy my Django app to AWS ElasticBeanStalk. Everything works fine with Docker compose on my local computer. But when it runs on AWS it gives me this:
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsOKp.png)

> docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config/app/Dockerfile
    command: sh /config/on-container-start.sh
    hostname: app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
```

> Nginx

```
# define group app
upstream app {
  # balancing by ip
  ip_hash;

  # define server app
  server app:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  # all requests proxies to app
  location / {
         proxy_pass http://app/;
    }

  # only respond to port 8000
  listen 8000;

  # domain localhost
  server_name localhost;
}
```

> In settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Post error message as text

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the `link` option ?

So, your compose should be like this :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config/app/Dockerfile
    command: sh /config/on-container-start.sh
    hostname: app
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
    links:
      - app
```

the option `depends on` is for launch the dependencies before the app.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it still gives me the same error.